# Migrating Timer to Observation API in the Spring Boot 3

Tags: spring-boot, metrics, micrometer, spring-micrometer

As of Spring Boot 3, the Micrometer timer is needed to migrate to the new Observation API as stated in [the documentation](https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer/wiki/Migrating-to-new-1.10.0-Observation-API).

However, there is only an example for Timer.sample and I need to know about Timer.record(timeElapsed).

I have a method called getTimer:

```
Timer getTimer(string a){
 return meterRegistry.timer("module",
                    "runtime", a); //tags
}
Timer timedd =  getTimer(a);
timedd.record(timeElapsed)
```

Any idea about how to use Migrating Timer to Observation API?